# Super Dragon Ball Wish in Finale Open-Ended?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

In the recent Dragon Ball Super finale episode for the Tournament of Power saga

> Android 17 wishes back all the universes that were erased.

However, it does not seem clear which ones this wish encompasses.

According to the lore in much earlier episodes, there were originally 18 universes not including the World of Void, 6 of which were already erased by Zen-Oh long before the Tournament of Power began.

Is there any evidence to support whether or not these 6 other universes were also revived by the wish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the wish was pretty cleverly worded as it gives the show a lot more options in the future. Then again we can't be sure whether it was done on purpose. It could be for one of 2 reasons:

1. **For Future Arcs**: Since we already got a taste of 8 Universes in the tournament of power, they could perhaps introduce even more powerful characters from those erased universes. Perhaps a very powerful evil villain, or a God who has gone rogue. We won't know the same until a future iteration of Dragon Ball.
2. **To save out on time/ dialgue**: Perhaps, viewers might be thinking too much of it and considering the fact that there was very little time remaining in the last episode, maybe it made a lot more sense than Saying Revive all the Universes that were erased during the course of the tournament of power. Considering it had to be said twice by both 17 and the Grand Priest.

As much as I like to believe it was intentional, I have a feeling it isn't considering the fact that 8 new Universes have already come into the picture that can be explored. Especially Universe 6 and Universe 11. Also, there exists 4 more Universes that didn't take part in the tournament of power which could be explored. Considering the abundant number of characters present, I don't see why they would want to bring more Universes into the picture. Then again, Dragon Ball has been pretty unpredictable in Super. We all thought Android 17 was dead but he ended up winning the tournament of power! So we won't know until release up the next iteration of the Dragon Ball Series.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being optimistic, but there were similar scenarios where the ambiguity of Dragon Ball wishes led to future events, like in Dragon Ball Z where Captain Ginyu was discovered much later, and it was revealed that the wish made on the original planet Namek during the battle with Frieza had brought him to earth along with everyone else.

Comment: @Patrick Roberts Either way I honestly don't think it matters because there are already many Universes left to explore in the series. Universe 6, 11 seems promising.  Also, there are four Universes which didn't take part in the tournament of power so hence those 4 too and if they really want more Universes, they could more or less have them use the Super Dragon Balls to wish them back again as well. So if there is a new series and they want to go that route, I'm pretty sure they'd try to cough up a reasonable excuse as to why so and so was possible.