# Was Universe 18 restored by the Super Dragon Balls?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

*Dragon Ball Super* ended with Android 17 wishing for all universes to be restored.

Does this mean Universe 18 has also been restored as it was erased by the Omni-King in the past?

Comment: I removed the last question regarding "new DB plot" because it's primarily opinion-based. Also, the 1st question might be answered objectively, but I'm not sure about the 2nd one. However, I'll leave it to users who have more experience in the DB series.

Comment: I'm assuming this question is based on a recent fan video from a prominent Dragon Ball Youtuber. That was primarily opinion based and has no association with the Dragon Ball Franchise. The first part of your question, has been answered by me [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/46279/super-dragon-ball-wish-in-finale-open-ended/46281?noredirect=1#comment60346_46281). I suggest this question be closed.